# Pygame Mixer "Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault" Error

Tags: python, pygame

Example;

```
from pygame import mixer
import threading
import time

def sound(file_path):
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(file_path)
    mixer.music.play()
    while mixer.music.get_busy():
        time.sleep(0.1)
    mixer.stop()
    mixer.quit()

while True:
    file_path = input("Enter your file path:")
    threading.Thread(target=sound,args={file_path}).start()
```

Sometimes when i run this code i get the following error:

`Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault`

Whats wrong in here?

Comment: I'd guess there's something *incompatible* with the sound file you're trying to load.  Maybe it has a split-second of corruption (or suchlike) in the file that `pygame.mixer.music` can't handle, but can't recover from either.

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to a sound file that demonstrates this problem?  It might be worth testing on PyGame 2, and making a bug report if it persists.